# Does Jw Player 6 requires flash player installed in local machine?

Tags: flash, jwplayer

I'm having a doubt about Jw Player 6, does the player requires any kind flash player installed in local machine for its smooth working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to have the Flash player installed in your local machine.